# Nested location doesn't work properly

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration

I cannot debug this piece of nginx configuration:
I want to add some headers to all requests for a `.pdf` file
Then I want to remove a token which I add to my veiw directory to avoid unwanted browser's cache:

```
location /static {
    location ~* \.pdf$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Content-Disposition 'inline';
    }
    #Remove Anti cache token
    rewrite "^/static[0-9]{10}/(.*)$" /static/$1 last;
    ...
}
```

There is no nginx syntax error but requesting a `.pdf` for shows a 404 not found error means that rewrite doesn't apply on the request.

Any help is very appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When `nginx` chooses a `location` to process a request, it may choose the inner or outer `location` block. It does not combine the statements from both.

The `rewrite` is not inherited by the nested `location`. If you want the `rewrite` to apply to all locations, you should place it in `server` block scope.

The regular expression of your `rewrite` statement is sufficiently specific, that it can be moved as is.

For example:

```
rewrite "^/static[0-9]{10}/(.*)$" /static/$1 last;

location /static {
    location ~* \.pdf$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Content-Disposition 'inline';
    }
    ...
}
```

Of course, it may be more efficient to just repeat the `rewrite` statement in both `location` blocks.

---

An alternative approach is to avoid the `rewrite` altogether and use a regular expression `location` to remove the anti-cache token by using an `alias` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for more.

For example:

```
location ~ "^(?<prefix>/static)[0-9]{10}(?<suffix>/.*)$" {
    alias /path/to/root$prefix$suffix;

    location ~* \.pdf$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Content-Disposition 'inline';
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that regular expression `location` block have a different evaluation order to prefix `location` blocks. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... The `rewrite` must be applied to all requests ask a file inside static directory and specially for this reason I want to use nested locations. also I have more locations like what I said in the question. what's your idea? should I repeat the line in ALL location blocks I want it?

Comment: I don't know which would be the best solution for you. But I have added an alternative solution for you to consider.

Answer (score 1):

While the best answer for this question is what I checked as the best I want to post the solution I used to solve my problem. It's not necessary to define a nested location block to add a header to some of requests. Instead I used an if to check a regex condition and do what I want.
Look at the following block I wrote to handle this:

```
location /static {
    if ( $request_uri ~* \.pdf$ ) {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Content-Disposition 'inline';
    }

    #Remove Anti cache token
    rewrite "^/static[0-9]{10}/(.*)$" /static/$1 last;
    ...
}
```